# Testing Clustering Variables

Tags: clustering, t-test, fuzzy

I have two clusters. Those two clusters were obtained using Fuzzy C-Means with 8 variables. I'd like to know which variables have important role in differentiating the two clusters. Can I use t test for each variables to see if the two clusters have different mean in those variables? Do you any better idea what test I should use?

Comment: Yes you may use, variable by variable, any test comparing groups. Look at effect size such as Cohen D. You may also treat p-value as "effect size". You should _not_, however, make inferences about whether test is significant or not in respect to a population, - because clusters were produced exactly to differ maximally.

Comment: Presumably you have some definition for what a good clustering is?  Optimize the clustering based on the different variables and see how much of an improvement is caused by each one.

Comment: Please spell out your acronyms. What is "FCM"?

Comment: @ttnphns Knowing the quality of the information you usually share, I doubt that you meant to say "You may also treat p-value as '"effect size"'.

Comment: @rolando2, I've taken it in quotes. As if effect size, affected by the groups' `n`. Sometimes one would want such affectedness

Answer (score -1):

There's a couple things here. In response to your question directly, that's probably not the best idea unless you're going to correct for the fact that making multiple comparisons. Briefly, since this topic has been covered pretty heavily, if you have a lot of variable pairs and you're testing to see whether there is a difference in means between the variables, if you compute a lot of pairwise t-tests you'll end up rejecting null hypothesis purely by chance (check out the classification of m tests in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem this page for a good description). What I would recommend is either doing those t-test but then correcting with some method (hochbergs, FDR, bonferoni).

But aside from that, I'm a little confused at how you're using FCM. FCM typically gives back weights that tell you how much a particular observation belongs to a particular cluster. Are you just saying "whichever cluster has a higher weight for observation x is the cluster that observation x belongs to"?

Comment: thank you for your answer. yes FCM gives those weights in partiton matrix. but i dont know if we can get any information regarding which clustering variables have role in differentiating clusters using the partition matrix...as far as i know we can only use it to determine which data belongs to which cluster.

Comment: The weights (w_ij) in that matrix (P) certainly depend on the "clustering variables" as you call them so the w_ij  contain some information on membership. One thing you could try (and I'd be very interested to how this works out) is to replicate observations based on w_ij and then use a hypothesis test along with some form of a multiple comparisons correction to decide the "importance" of certain variables. That is, replicate x_i round(100*w_ij) times for cluster j and round(100*w_ij') for cluster j' and then perform your hypothesis test on the "psuedo-bootstrapped" sample.

Comment: No problem, if it's not a sensitive thing, I'd love to see how it works out.

Comment: @NickThieme Significance tests don't apply at all for such a situation because the clusters were formed through a cluster analysis.  Of course they will be highly different--the algorithm created them so that they would be.  There is no question as to how different the clusters would be by chance.  Cheers ~

Comment: Oh wow, it's been a while since I've looked at this. Hmmm, I'm not sure I agree with your comment, though. The goal isn't to discover whether the clusters are different (like you said, that's already done.), but to discover whether the clusters are different in particular variables. If we have a dataset x =c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5), and y = c(1,1,1,1,1,5,5,5,5,5) and we cluster that, you'll get the 1's in one cluster and the 5's in the other. If you calculate the means for each variable and each cluster, you'll get m_1=c(3,1) and m_2=c(3,5) telling you that they differ on y.

Comment: I agree that the clusters' mean differences (esp. in light of within-group variation) are informative and relevant, but I don't believe p-values contribute anything in this situation and may well mislead.  "The prob. that differences as large as or larger than __ would occur merely by chance," which is what the p-values would tell, can't be useful when the clusters were formed on purpose, with the very goal of maximizing group differences.